# Correlating the screen information from electron.desktopCapturer.getSources() and electron.screen.getAllDisplays()

Tags: electron

I'm grabbing some information about the user's screen resolutions and screen setup.

`electron.desktopCapturer.getSources()` returns [DesktopCapturerSource[]](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/structures/desktop-capturer-source.md) which I use to get a thumbnail of the screen.

`electron.screen.getAllDisplays()` returns [Display[]](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/structures/display.md) which I use to get the screen dimensions, rotation, etc.

Both are arrays of equal size, wherein each element represents different information about the desktop screen. They have names and ids, neither of which seem to match up between the objects. I'm unsure of how exactly I can correlate the data between the two objects to guarantee I am talking about the same screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join both of the calls and correspond `id` from the objects returned by `screen.getAllDisplays()` with `display_id` from the objects returned by `desktopCapturer.getSources()`.

Please note that this was tried on MacOS Big Sur with Electron 12 and that the results may not be the same with other operating systems.

Example output from `screen.getAllDisplays()`:

```
[
  {
    id: 2077748985,
    bounds: { x: 0, y: 0, width: 1792, height: 1120 },
    workArea: { x: 0, y: 25, width: 1792, height: 1095 },
    accelerometerSupport: 'unknown',
    monochrome: false,
    colorDepth: 30,
    colorSpace: '{primaries:BT709, transfer:IEC61966_2_1_HDR, matrix:RGB, range:FULL}',
    depthPerComponent: 10,
    size: { width: 1792, height: 1120 },
    displayFrequency: 59,
    workAreaSize: { width: 1792, height: 1095 },
    scaleFactor: 2,
    rotation: 0,
    internal: true,
    touchSupport: 'unknown'
  }
]
```

Example output from `desktopCapturer.getSources()`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Entire Screen",
        "id": "screen:2077748985:0",
        "thumbnail": {
            "isMacTemplateImage": false
        },
        "display_id": "2077748985",
        "appIcon": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Hello World!",
        "id": "window:33637:0",
        "thumbnail": {
            "isMacTemplateImage": false
        },
        "display_id": "",
        "appIcon": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Hello World!",
        "id": "window:33636:0",
        "thumbnail": {
            "isMacTemplateImage": false
        },
        "display_id": "",
        "appIcon": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Correlating the screen information from electron.desktopCapturer.getSources() and electron.screen.getAllDisplays() - Stack Overflow",
        "id": "window:3257:0",
        "thumbnail": {
            "isMacTemplateImage": false
        },
        "display_id": "",
        "appIcon": null
    },
    {
        "name": "electron-fun — Electron Helper (Renderer) ◂ npm TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal SHELL=/bin/zsh — 127×68",
        "id": "window:32731:0",
        "thumbnail": {
            "isMacTemplateImage": false
        },
        "display_id": "",
        "appIcon": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Calculator",
        "id": "window:32797:0",
        "thumbnail": {
            "isMacTemplateImage": false
        },
        "display_id": "",
        "appIcon": null
    }
]
```

Note that `id` is: 2077748985 and `display_id` is also: 2077748985.